# Making pages in a menu appear conditionally

Tags: menus, pages

How do I make a page (dis)appear conditionally in a menu? I had something like this in mind:

```
if(condition) 
    //show_page_in_menu
```

I would prefer an answer that doesn't incorporate an external plugin.

Comment: do you mean a `wp_nav_menu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_nav_menu_objects` or `wp_nav_menu_items` hooks to add your filter function.

```
function my_hide_menu_items($objects) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $objects;

    foreach ( $objects as $k=>$object ) {
        if ( YOUR CONDITION ) {  // if $object shouldn't be displayed
            unset($objects[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $objects;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_hide_menu_items', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, many internets for you, sir!